# Image processing, what technique can be used to determine shortest path in a bitmap

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision, maps

Given this image (converted to black and white bitmap), what technique/method can I use to draw an overlay showing the shortest path(s) between region A and B?

I'm new to image processing, I need directions where to start.
Though, I'm familiar with some machine learning techniques.

[image: Shortest path]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a regular gridded image, there are specialized algorithms for computing geodesic distance which can make assumptions about the structure of the graph. In general, this is a graph theory problem.

https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/12/13/exploring-shortest-paths-part-5/